# Two rpms with the same prefix name on one repository

Tags: centos, mysql, yum, repository

I am using CentOS, I have a local repository and I want to add mysql server and mysql cluster rpms on it 
so I added all required rpm and all dependencies.

**At client that added my repo**

list all rpm with MYSQL in repo

```
[root@s2 ~]# yum list available |grep MySQL
MySQL-Cluster-client-gpl.x86_64        7.3.5-1.el6                     localrepo
MySQL-Cluster-server-gpl.x86_64        7.3.5-1.el6                     localrepo
MySQL-Cluster-shared-compat-gpl.x86_64 7.3.5-1.el6                     localrepo
MySQL-server.x86_64                    5.6.17-1.el6                    localrepo
```

try to install mysql server

```
[root@s2 ~]# yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
localrepo                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Package MySQL-server is obsoleted by MySQL-Cluster-server-gpl, trying to install MySQL-Cluster-server-gpl-7.3.5-1.el6.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MySQL-Cluster-server-gpl.x86_64 0:7.3.5-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                      Arch       Version            Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 MySQL-Cluster-server-gpl     x86_64     7.3.5-1.el6        localrepo     142 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 142 M
Installed size: 612 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

The yum install `mysql cluster server` instated of `mysql server`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `yum install MySQL-server.x86_64`

Comment: Not working ....

Comment: `yum install mysql.x86_64`

Comment: No package mysql.x86_64 available.

Comment: O.o I know that normally running the command `yum install <insert package name>` works.  Specifically you listed `MySQL-server.x86_64`.  That should work.  The `mysql.x86_64` the one that I pulled from my Fedora 15 VM that I'm running.